# Trying to only display two decades on axis of box-plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet, geom

[image: My Plot]

Hi!

This is how my plot looks at the moment...
Want to try and only display decades 1980 and 2010 in my box plots.
This is how my code looks now:

```
 gender_race_income <- ggplot(data = gender_pay_gap, aes(x = factor(decade), y = income, colour 
                                                    = sex)) +
   geom_boxplot() +
   coord_flip() +
   facet_grid(rows = vars(race)) +
   scale_y_log10() +
   theme_bw() +
   scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow. You can subset your data using `filter()` from `dplyr` and then pass this onto the ggplot using the `%>%` pipe.

```
gender_pay_gap %>%
  dplyr::filter(decade == 1980 | decade == 2010) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(decade), y = income, colour = sex)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(race)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```